# Why printw does display in this case?

Tags: c, ncurses

Why in this case, `printw` displays "Blah" ? I use `nocbreak`. So `printw` is not supposed to produce output normally, because the output is line-buffered.

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    initscr();
    nocbreak();
    printw("Blah");
    refresh();
    while (1);
}
```

Comment: "Printw() is not supposed to display normally, because it bufferize." What do you mean by this?

Comment: because of _refresh_ ?

Comment: the printw() function is not supposed to display in this case, whereas it does if you execute this code... So I don't understand why.

Comment: Nope, i replace the refresh() by getch() and it's the same..

Comment: It display too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the call to `refresh`.

The [refresh man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/refresh) does not explicitly state it, but it seems to apply the buffered outputs as well.

Without the call to `refresh`, no output is shown.

If you add a call to `getch` instead of `refresh`, you get the output too, because `getch` does a `wrefresh`. [Man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch):

> If the window is not a pad, and it has been moved or modified since the last call to wrefresh, wrefresh will be called before another character is read.

To see the different behavior for inputs in cbreak/nocbreak mode, you can use this program:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char c, i;
    initscr();
    noecho();  // switch off display of typed characters by the tty

    printw("cbreak\n");
    cbreak();
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        c = getch();
        printw("%c", c);
    }

    printw("\nnocbreak\n");
    nocbreak();
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        c = getch();
        printw("%c", c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In cbreak mode, the program sees the five input characters as you type them (and outputs immediately due to `getch`). In nocbreak mode, they will be received and output only after you press return.

Comment: Ok ok ok, I did this test to see how cbreak() works. Do you have a test to show that it works?
Because I had used refresh() to update the terminal but now I don't know what to use...

Comment: So you want to see that output in nocbreak mode is line-buffered? You see this because without `refresh` nothing is displayed. If you `printw("Blah\n");` however, it is printed even without the `refresh`.

Comment: You are right. `cbreak`/`nocbreak` is about input: Does the program receive key strokes immediately or only after newline. "Normally, the tty driver buffers typed characters until a newline or carriage return is typed. The cbreak routine disables line buffering and erase/kill character-processing (interrupt and flow control characters are unaffected), making characters typed by the user immediately available to the program." For the output, you always need a refresh (or similar) to make it visible.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `printw` is ***not*** line-buffered.  ncurses initializes the terminal to *raw mode* and simulates *cooked mode* as needed.  But that applies only to ***input***.  For output, ncurses will immediately write the relevant updates to the screen as noted in the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html#h3-refresh_wrefresh):

> The **`refresh`** and **`wrefresh`** routines (or **`wnoutrefresh`** and  doupdate)  must
>   be called to get actual output to the terminal, as other routines merely manipulate data structures.  *The routine **`wrefresh`** copies  the  named
>   window  to  the  **physical  screen**,  taking into account what is already
>   there to do optimizations.  The **`refresh`** routine is the same, using **`stdscr`** as the default window.*  Unless **`leaveok`** has been enabled, the physical cursor of the terminal is left at the location of  the  cursor  for
>   that window.

The ***physical screen*** is your terminal, of course.  ncurses remembers what's there by recording it in [**`curscr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_variables.3x.html#h3-The-Current-Screen):

> This  implementation  of  curses uses a special window **`curscr`** to record
>          its updates to the terminal screen.
>
> This is referred to as the ***"physical screen"***  in  the  [curs_refresh(3x)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html)
>   and [curs_outopts(3x)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_outopts.3x.html) manual pages.

From ncurses' viewpoint, the terminal (that you *see*) and **`curscr`** are the same thing.

For [**`printw`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_printw.3x.html#h2-DESCRIPTION), the manual page says it acts as if it calls [**`waddstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html), and that in turn calls **`waddch`**:

> These functions write the (null-terminated) character string str on the
>   given window.  It is similar to calling [**`waddch`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Adding-characters) once for each  character
>   in the string.

Comment: Ok ok thanks for your answer, but now i don’t know when it might be relevant to use cbreak(), since printw doesn’t act as printf !

Comment: `cbreak` tells ncurses (part of) how to simulate cooked versus raw *input* modes, so it's not relevant to `printw` (an *output* function).